# C++ implicit conversions: Order of the conversions

Tags: c++, type-conversion

Here is some parts from cpprefrence: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast

Implicit conversion sequence consists of the following, in this order:

1) zero or one standard conversion sequence

2) zero or one user-defined conversion

3) zero or one standard conversion sequence

I think 1)->2) or 2)->3) conversion order is common.
 But there is example for 1)->2)->3)?

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
struct X {
  X(int a) {}
};

const X x = 5.0;
```

First there is standard conversion from `double` to `int`, then user-defined conversion from `int` to `X`, then standard conversion from `X` to `const X`. (Qualification adjustment from `non-const` to `const` is kind of standard conversion according to the c++ reference.)

I am not 100% sure about the last conversion, maybe we could say that the object is already constructed const? We could use `volatile` instead of `const` too.

Comment: `void fun(const X x); fun(5.0); ` I think out this one from  your example.